# Accumulo: How to index data for efficient queries?

Tags: accumulo

I need an efficient indexing schema to store alerts. Each alert has the following attributes:

- alertId
- timestamp
- type
- location

I need to perform the following queries:

- How many alerts were on created in a defined date range?
- How many alerts of type X were created in a defined date range?
- How many alerts from location Y were created in a defined date range?

My initial thought was to index a follows:

```
ROWID -> alertId_timestamp,
CF -> attribute (type, location),
CQ -> value
```

However I think the query performance will be poor for my #2 & #3 query use cases. How should I index my data?

Comment: How large of a date range do you need to support searching and what is the expectation on how fast each of your 3 queries would run?

Comment: Date range shouldn't be more than 30 days.  I hope each query can be returned within 3 seconds.

Comment: One more question: how many alerts per day, both number of alerts and average size of alert (to compute total bytes per day).

Comment: Hundreds of thousands of alerts per day.  Average alert size ~30 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know those are going to be your only queries, you could insert your data as such:

```
RowID     |  CF    |  CQ    | Value 
Timestamp | "TYPE" | <type> | alertID
Timestamp | "LOC"  | <loc>  | alertID
```

Yes, you are inserting the data 2x, but this is "Big Data", right, so storage space should not be a big concern.  All of your queries are time based and are just doing counts, so you should put the timestamp as your RowID so that you can do `Range` over the rows and filter what you want on the `CF/CQ` with `fetchColumnFamily` or .  You could also try combining the CF/CQ together such as "TYPE_Foo", and "LOC_Boston" if you know that you're only going to be looking for specific types/locations, but this will limit you if you're trying to find all/range of types/locations.  Note that you'll also probably want to use some sort of iterator to do server side aggregation [Does Accumulo support aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048613/does-accumulo-support-aggregation)

Comment: Thanks for feedback!  Given your suggestion how would I use an iterator to aggregate the total number of alerts for a given timestamp (or range of timestamps)?